# Angular Input value is not changing in FormArray

Tags: html, angular, typescript, formarray

I have a FormArray in PreprocesssingForm. Here, Sequence No is not getting changed when I add a new row.

```
<tr class="mat-row" *ngFor="let dynamic of PreprocessingForm.controls.arithmeticItems['controls']; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
    <td> {{ i+1 }} </td>

    <td class="mat-cell">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="width: 4rem;text-align: center;">
        <input matInput formControlName="operational_sequence_no" type="text" value = {{ i+1 }} readonly>
    </mat-form-field>
    </td>
```

`<td> {{ i+1 }} </td>` is showing correctly 1 2 3 4 5.
I tried `value = {{i+1}}, [value] = "i+1", value = "{{i+1}}"`.
But, It is showing 1 1 1 1 1.

`[ngModel] = "i+1"` is working, but console is telling that it is depreceated.

Comment: I think you have to set the value in the .ts file into the FormControl.

Comment: Yes, I did. `sequence_no: [1]`. I changed it to [""], Now the input box is empty when a row is added.

Answer (score 1):

if you use FormControl **not** use "value". You should give value to the FormControl

I imagine you have a getter(*)

```
get arithmeticItems()
{
   return PreprocessingForm.controls.arithmeticItems as FromArray
}
```

And a function that return a formGroup

```
newArithmeticItem()
{
   return new FormGroup({
     operational_sequence_no:new FormControl(0)
     ...
   })
}
```

When add an element

```
addArithmeticItem()
{
    this.arithmeticItems.push(this.newArithmeticItem())
}
```

The only is change your newArithmeticItem like:

```
newArithmeticItem()
{
   return new FormGroup({
     //see how you give value when you create the formControl
     operational_sequence_no:new FormControl(this.arithmeticItems.controls.length+1) 
     ...
   })
}
```

But... be careful, if you remove an item you should "recalculate" the "operational_sequence"

```
removeArithmeticItem(index:number)
{
    this.arithmeticItems.removeAt(index)
    //renum operational_sequence
    //I renum all instead of only from index to last one
    //If you have not a laaaaaarge quantity it's OK
    this.aritmeticItems.controls.forEach((x:AbstractControl,i:number)=>{
       x.patchValue("operational_sequence_no",i+1)
    })
}
```

(*)I know you have not, but it's good to have a getter of the formArrays